# List<T> Sort Memory Leak

Tags: c#, .net, linq, memory-leaks

How to fix memory leaks when sorting generic lists in .NET?

```
private void ManageXmlIndex(XmlDocument xmlDocIndicatorIndex)
{
    indexList = repoManager.ParseIndex(xmlDocIndicatorIndex);
    indexList.Sort((x, y) => y.Created.CompareTo(x.Created));
    view.UpdateIndex(indexList);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

The same happens when I'm using `linq OrderBy`.

Is custom comparing function can solve the problem?

The bug happens due to the `List.Sort`. When I comment out the `Sort` line, the bug disappears.

Comment: Why do you assume this is a memory leak?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Here is the full stack: http://s28.postimg.org/kj0iww8ul/screenshot_1089.png

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov .net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a memory leak. It's simply the way the compiler is caching your `Comparison<IndicatorPropReport>` as a `static` delegate at the call site, thus saving you the need to create an instance of it for each invocation.

If you look at this simplified example:

```
var ints = new List<int> { 3, 2, 1, 8, 5 };
ints.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
```

And look at what the compiler generates using an .NET decompiler:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Comparison<int> CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int> { 3,2,1,8,5 };
    List<int> arg_51_0 = ints;

    if (Program.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 == null)
    {
        Program.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2 = 
                new Comparison<int>(Program.<Main>b__1);
    }
    arg_51_0.Sort(Program.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private static int <Main>b__1(int x, int y)
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

You see that the `Comparsion<int>` was cached as a `static` delegate. The same behavior is what happens in your method call.

Note this behavior is pre Roslyn. [Roslyn changes the way delegates are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897647/delegate-caching-behavior-changes-in-roslyn) by creating a display class instead of the static delegate, even when there's no captured variables.

Comment: I supposed that this is the case, however, I hoped to find a solution to release it after the method/class is not needed anymore. Does it hold the whole containing class in the memory or only the delegate?

Comment: @MiroslavPopov The class isn't kept in memory. It will be eligible for collection.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer from Microsoft support:

> `List<T>` creates an empty array of `T` in its static constructor. The
>   array is stored in a static field of `List<T>` so it will be alive until
>   the AppDomain dies. So, not a memory leak.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/dee3c1ee-fb63-43f1-88be-413136afe3ed/memory-leak-in-generic-collection

I hope that support your question.