# Compiled project has different behavior when built with VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Last week I've installed the `Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise` edition (further named: `VS2015`). I want to perform some test before switching to the newer version. For example backwards compatibility of the project files. I'm ignoring currently all `C# 6.0` features, because not all team members have installed their updates to support `C# 6.0`.

My problem is, that a solution/project which is built with `VS2015` has a different behavior in case of exception throwing to the same solution/project which was built with `VS2013 (Premium)`.

Following I'm going to describe the scenario with the code snippets which are failing when built with `VS2015`.

The behavior of the project built with `VS2015` changed as follows:
The code below is throwing an `System.ArgumentException` with following message: `Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance. Parameter name: method`

**Code sippets**

```
//A delegate to convert string values from an array (e3k.Values) to the property type of the desired object.
Func<TE3K, int, Type, object> stringFromDictionary = (e3k, index, type) =>
{
    //handle enums
    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        if (typeof (TE3K) == typeof (VoucherHeader)) //maybe not so good
            return VoucherEnumConverter.ToWebEnum(e3k.Values[index], type, e3k.Values);

        return DefaultEnumConverter.ToWebEnum(e3k.Values[index], type);
    }

    //set default value, false if api sends null
    if (type == typeof(Boolean) && e3k.Values[index] == null)
         return false;

    //fix exception when a value like "0" or "1" is converted to boolean.
    if (type == typeof(Boolean) && (e3k.Values[index] == "0" || e3k.Values[index] == "1"))
        return Convert.ChangeType(Int32.Parse(e3k.Values[index]), type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    //handle nullables
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null)
          return Convert.ChangeType(e3k.Values[index], Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return Convert.ChangeType(e3k.Values[index], type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
};
MethodInfo getStrValueFromDict = stringFromDictionary.Method;
```

Description: The object `TE3K` is an object from an external .dll which I have to convert into an object I can work with. This object of type `TE3K`has an array with its values obviously they're all `Strings`. The parameter `int`provides the index for the array (`e3k.Values[i]`) The parameter `Type`is the `PropertyType`which the string value must be converted into.

```
//get mapper, sets the index needed in `e3k.Values[index]` for each property of `TWeb`
Dictionary<PropertyInfo, int> mapper = Converter.GetMapper<TE3K, TWeb>();
foreach (var property in mapper)
{
    Expression propertyValue = default(Expression);
    if (property.Key.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)) //not relevant for this case
    {
        propertyValue = Expression.Call(getDateValueFromDict, r, Expression.Constant(property.Value));
    }
    else if (property.Key.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)) //not relevant in this case
    {
        propertyValue = Expression.Call(getDateValueFromDictSave, r, Expression.Constant(property.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        //exception is thrown on this line but only when project is compiled in VS2015
        propertyValue = Expression.Call(getStrValueFromDict, r, Expression.Constant(property.Value), Expression.Constant(property.Key.PropertyType)); 
    }
    UnaryExpression boxedValue = Expression.Convert(propertyValue, property.Key.PropertyType);
    bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(property.Key, boxedValue));
    FieldList.Add(property.Value);
}
```

I now what causes this exception under normal conditions. It's thrown when you make a call to a `non static` method inside the delegate which is passed into the first parameter of `Expression.Call(_delegate, args, ...)` or if one of the arguments is a non constant value. (Correct me if I'm wrong here, that is how I understand this.)

**Summary**

Obviously I'm pretty confused by this behavior. The exception mentioned earlier only occurs when the project is built with `VS2015`. When built with `VS2013`the code runs as expected. Are there differences in how visual studio builds and optimizes code between those two versions?

**What I've tried**

- Compiling on Release/Debug both don't change the behavior.
- Changing C# version does also change nothing.

Feel free to explain extensively if you know a cause. If you need information please ask, I provide them if available.

Comment: *Changing C# version does also change nothing.* Yes, because [it doesn't do what one expects it to do](http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/04/what-does-the-langversion-switch-do/)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Nice to know. I was trying to play with some settings to see if the behavior changes, but I wasn't really expecting that they change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown if `getStrValueFromDict` is non-static, not if you have non-static calls inside it like you've written. You need to handle the case that `getStrValueFromDict` is compiled to an instance method. This could definitely be different based on the used compiler.

```
Expression instance = getStrValueFromDict.IsStatic ? null : Expression.Constant(stringFromDictionary.Target);
propertyValue = Expression.Call(instance, getStrValueFromDict, r, Expression.Constant(property.Value), Expression.Constant(property.Key.PropertyType));
```

Here is some background information about why some delegates are now compiled to instance methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897727/631802

Comment: Nice, Thank you. That solved this issue. I think I should read a little bit more about the Roslyn compiler.