# System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a target.' only with VS 2017 not with VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, system.reflection

I have been using the [KendoDynamicLinq](https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers) library for years on this project with no problems. I started to use VS 2017 Community Edition instead of VS 2013 on this same project/code and if I run the project with VS 2017 I get this exception:
`System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a target.'`

But if I run it with VS 2013, no problem, no exception and all is working.

I have been wracking my head around this but I cannot seem to find the answer. Any help or direction to point me to would be appreciate it.

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethod(string methodName, MethodInfo methodTypes, int genericArgumentsCount)
        {
            var methods = from method in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                          let parameters = method.GetParameters()
                          let genericArguments = method.GetGenericArguments()
                          where method.Name == methodName &&
                            genericArguments.Length == genericArgumentsCount &&
                            parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual((Type[])methodTypes.Invoke(null, genericArguments))
                          select method;
            return methods.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

The line that is throwing is this:

```
parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual((Type[])methodTypes.Invoke(null, genericArguments))
```

Do you see anything here that can work with VS2013 but not in VS 2017. No changes to the solution or the target framework.

Comment: The problem is actually in the caller of GetMethod who passed methodTypes. They were supposed to pick a static method and picked an instance method instead. Just off the top of my head, there was change in the C# compiler that changed certain kinds of lambda expressions from static methods to instance methods on a singleton closure class in that time frame.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it, hard to say, this library receives a IQuarable collection and applies filters and aggregators from a UI Kendo grid. In this case it is a sum of a certain field. Not sure there what is the method and how to intercept it. I'll investigate more an post findings.

Comment: If you are recompiling this library from the source code in VS 2017 then it makes sense. The underlying change in the C# compiler causing the issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897647/delegate-caching-behavior-changes-in-roslyn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you mike z for pointing me to right direction. 
I am now checking if the methodTypes passed in is static or not and if it is static I am now passing in null as a target object. But if it is not static, then I create an instance of the object and pass that instead. Here is the new calling code:

```
var m = ((Func<Type, Type[]>)this.GetType().GetMethod("SumAvgFunc", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .MakeGenericMethod(proptype).Invoke(null, null)).GetMethodInfo();
                    object obj = null;
                    if (!m.IsStatic)
                    {
                        obj = Activator.CreateInstance(m.DeclaringType);
                    }
                    return GetMethod(aggregate, m, 1, obj).MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

So I added a parameter to the GetMethod() method that takes an object which will be null if the method is static otherwise it will be an instance of the class whom method is a member. Here is GetMethod :

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethod(string methodName, MethodInfo methodTypes, int genericArgumentsCount, object obj)
        {
            var methods = from method in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                          let parameters = method.GetParameters()
                          let genericArguments = method.GetGenericArguments()
                          where method.Name == methodName &&
                            genericArguments.Length == genericArgumentsCount &&
                            parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual((Type[])methodTypes.Invoke(obj, genericArguments))
                          select method;
            return methods.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Now all works just fine as it was working before with VS 2013.
Thank you mike z